# Prove the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}v(n)/n = 0$ where $v(n)$ is the number of prime factors of the integer $n$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, prime-numbers

Let $v(n)$ be the number of prime factors of the integer $n$. For example, $v(8) = 3$ and $v(5) = 1$. Prove: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{v(n)}{n} = 0$$

I was thinking about the sandwich theorem, just because this exercise belongs to a chapter that talks about this (Intro to Real Analysis - Arthur Mattuck). The lower bound can be $1/n$ but I could't find an upper bound.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Note that $v(n) \le \log_2 n$.

Comment: Alright, that helps a lot! Thanks! But anyway, I still have to prove that $log_{2}n / n$ goes to zero without using L'Hospital. Until now, as this is a Real Analysis course, I'm "allowed" to use the definition of limit and the common theorems as limit of sums, products, quotients, etc. Any idea?

Comment: Try the substitution $n = 2^k$.  (You will have to take advantage of properties of $\lg n \equiv \log_2 n$.)

Comment: @BrianTung: That's not okay unless you have **real** $k$ tending to infinity. It's not enough to prove for positive integer $k$ that $\frac{k}{2^k} \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an interesting purely elementary way to prove that $\frac{\log(n)}{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

For any $n \ge 4$, we have $\frac{\log(n^2)}{n^2} = \frac{2\log(n)}{n^2} \le \frac{1}{2} \frac{\log(n)}{n}$. Also, for any $m \in [n,n^2]$, we have $\frac{\log(m)}{m} \le \frac{\log(n^2)}{n} = 2 \frac{\log(n)}{n}$. Together, these give that for any $n \ge 2^{2^k}$, we have $\frac{\log(n)}{n} \le 2(\frac{1}{2})^k$.